# AD_ID Declaration Not Recognized by Play Console

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-play-console

My app target API 33, and do have ads.
I choose "Yes" on advertising ID.
Adding `<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID" />` on AndroidManifest.xml file.

My app manifest include com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID and in Google Play Console - App Bundle Explorer - Permissions - I can found "com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID"

But when submit to review this error shows up:

> Your declaration on Play Console says that your app uses advertising ID. Your manifest file doesn't include the com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID permission

How to deal with this error?

Comment: I had the same problem, and it turns out that other people are having similar problems.
: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73139866/android-13-ad-id-declaration-not-recognized-by-play-console

It seems to be a bug on the Google Play Console side, but I'm not sure.
I decided to go ahead with "Release without permission" as mentioned in the comments.
If you have a solution or have any information, please share.

Comment: And I verified that in my internal test version I can get a valid AD ID value by calling AdvertisingIdClient.getAdvertisingIdInfo().

Comment: Does anyone know if this is solved somehow by Google?